Dataframe Expansion: Generating Genomic Positions +/- 250 Nucleotides
I have a df that looks like (with 300k more rows of other genomic coordinates):
    chromosome  start     end   
    chr1      11859      11879


I want to expand the df such that for each row, it will include every position of the given coordinate centered around 250 nucleotides on each side. I need to do this in an efficient way since my df is expected to be millions of rows long after this process (probably avoid for loop). For example, the chr1:11859-11879 row will be expanded to 21 rows.
how to calculate:
    chromosome  start     end   
    chr1      11859-250   11859+250
    chr1      11860-250   11860+250
    ...
    chr1      11879-250   11879+250

final df:
    chromosome  start     end   
0   chr1       11609       12109
1   chr1       11610       12110
...
20  chr1        11629      12129

It seems so simple, but I think I'm using overly complicated methods to get to this point.
Here's the general formula:
chromosome     start            end 
chr1          START-250         START+250
chr1         (START+1)-250     (START+1)+250
...
chr1           END-250          END+250


You can use Index.repeat by difference of end and start and repeat rows by DataFrame.loc, create counter by GroupBy.cumcount per index values add start column, last add and subtract 250 and DataFrame.reset_index with parameter drop=True for avoid duplicated index values:
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['end'].sub(df['start']).add(1)), ['chromosome','start']]
counter = out['start'].add(out.groupby(level=0).cumcount())

out = (out.assign(start = counter.sub(250), end = counter.add(250))
          .reset_index(drop=True))
print (out)
   chromosome  start    end
0        chr1  11609  12109
1        chr1  11610  12110
2        chr1  11611  12111
3        chr1  11612  12112
4        chr1  11613  12113
5        chr1  11614  12114
6        chr1  11615  12115
7        chr1  11616  12116
8        chr1  11617  12117
9        chr1  11618  12118
10       chr1  11619  12119
11       chr1  11620  12120
12       chr1  11621  12121
13       chr1  11622  12122
14       chr1  11623  12123
15       chr1  11624  12124
16       chr1  11625  12125
17       chr1  11626  12126
18       chr1  11627  12127
19       chr1  11628  12128
20       chr1  11629  12129

